# Force MSBuild to include the Owners element in the nuget .nuspec file

Tags: msbuild, nuget, nuspec

In my NuGet package creation, I am using the builtin Visual Studio (2019) functionality to create the package. I have included the both the `Authors` and `Owners` elements in my `.csproj` file, but only the `Authors` tag gets copied to the final package. I realize [the `Owners` element has been deprecated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/msbuild-targets#pack-target), but Visual Studio still displays that line in the NuGet Package Manager Description, and it would be preferable to have that information be complete (if it's not there, it looks like the package owner was sloppy and left info out that should have been added). I can add it back in manually after the package is generated, but that is a hassle. Can I force that `Owners` element to be added to the NuGet package automatically?

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE #1**

I have created a solution.

Check this: https://github.com/gcsizmadia/EgonsoftHU.NuspecProperties

**ORIGINAL**

Unfortunately not only MSBuild does not support `Owners` element but [in `.nuspec` file the `owners` element is also deprecated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuspec#owners):

> Important
>
> owners is deprecated. Use authors instead.
>
> A comma-separated list of the package creators using profile names on nuget.org. This is often the same list as in authors, **and is ignored when uploading the package to nuget.org**.

What is more, [nuget.org ignores `authors` element as well](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/nuget-org/publish-a-package#managing-package-owners-on-nugetorg):

> Although each NuGet package's .nuspec file defines the package's authors, **the nuget.org gallery does not use that metadata to define ownership**. Instead, nuget.org assigns initial ownership to the person who publishes the package.  This is either the logged-in user who uploaded the package through the nuget.org UI, or the users whose API key was used with `nuget SetApiKey` or `nuget push`.

I also checked the source code of `PackTask` and although it gets the value of `NuspecProperties` MSBuild property but it is used only if `NuspecFile` MSBuild property is also set. But in this case all package properties will be read from the specified `.nuspec` file and the related MSBuild properties will be ignored.

So it seems that currently there is no way to force putting an `owners` element into the dynamically generated `.nuspec` file automatically.

What can be done?

- Extract the `.nuspec` file from the generated `.nupkg` file.
- Update the `.nuspec` file as needed.
- Replace the `.nuspec` file in the `.nupkg` file with the updated one.

Comment: This is essentially what I said in my question 

Comment: @Conrad, have you checked my solution? :) I think I actually answered your `Can I force ...` question confirming the fact that there is no built-in way to do that and also I created an implementation of a workaround. I thought that you do this `.nuspec` editing manually, so it seemed to be a good idea for me to create a simple tool that uses the `Owners` (and also the `Summary`) MSBuild properties to do this `.nuspec` editing for you automatically. :) I'd appreciate if you marked my post as answer. :)